# lldb Immediate exit with status = -1 lost connection

Tags: debugging, lldb

I can't get llbm to run on my (2020 Intel) Macbook (with updated command line tools).

I create a file `test.c` containing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("hello world\n");
}
```

and then run `clang -g test.c -o prog`.
Now I run `lldb prog` and get the following output:

```
lldb prog
(lldb) target create "prog"
Current executable set to '/whatever/prog' (x86_64).
(lldb) run
Process 3934 launched: '/whatever/prog' (x86_64)
Process 3934 exited with status = -1 (0xffffffff) lost connection
```

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: From [here](https://anadoxin.org/blog/lost-connection-when-debugging-with-lldb-on-mavericks.html/), it might require `sudo /usr/sbin/DevToolsSecurity --enable` or `sudo dscl . append /Groups/_developer GroupMembership <your_username>`

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that reinstalling Xcode (instead of just updating the command line tools) fixed the issue.